# data brick write xlsx in dbsf (data brick file system)

Tags: python, excel, databricks

i'm creating a data frame in data brick
I can see this data frame, no problem. it's name is : **df_MA**

Now I want to store this data frame as excel file in my DBSF but nothing work

```
df_MA.to_excel("/dbsf/PATH/test.xlsx")
# error message 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbsf/PATH/test.xlsx'
```

If I only use

```
df_MA.to_excel("test.xlsx")
#no error message but can't find the file which is suposed to be created
```

i'm totaly new with data brick and I have hard problem to understand how DBSF work.. thanks for help

EDIT:

using same code than you giving me error:

[image]

the line in red give the error.

> oserror errno 95 operation not supported

The only one solution I found is:

Save the file in `databricks/drivers`

Then move the file and delet it from drivers..

e.g

```
  df_MA.to_excel('test.xlsx')
  shutil.copy2('test.xlsx','/dbfs/PATH/test1.xlsx')
  #copyfile(file, file_path)
  os.remove('test.xlsx')
```

I should be able to write or read /PATH

[image]

Comment: Where did you look for the file? Is that the full path to the file location?

Comment: `df_MA.to_excel("test.xlsx")` Yes this is full path but it's impossible to see where this is created

Comment: ***"can't find the file"***: Add [`print(os.getcwd())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) just before `df_MA.to_excel("test.xlsx")`

Comment: My guess is that it is storing the file in the current working directory of your databricks cluster: `/databricks/driver/`. Try `os.path.exists('/databricks/driver/test.xlsx')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just according to your code, it seems that your `df_MA` dataframe is created by `pandas` in databricks, because there is not a function `to_excel` for a PySpark dataframe and databricks does not support to convert a PySpark dataframe to an excel file, as the figure below as my experiment.

[image]

So I directly write the `pandas` dataframe `df` to an excel file `test.xlsx` in the current work directory, as the figure below.

[image]

Then, I tried to run the code like yours `df_MA.to_excel("/dbsf/PATH/test.xlsx")`, but there is an issue that the parent path should be `/dbfs`, bnot `/dbsf`, as the figure below.

[image]

So when you tried to write a file to a non-existing directory `PATH`, it would not work. As my figure below, it's necessary to first to make a new directory named `PATH` as you wish under the path `/dbfs`, the it works.

[image]

---

Update: I test for opening and modifying the `test.xlsx` file using `openpyxl`, as the code and figure below.

```
# Load test.xlsx and modify the `A1` cell
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/dbfs/PATH/test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    print([col.value for col in row])
ws['A1']='A1'
wb.save('/dbfs/PATH/test.xlsx')

# Load its modified version and print values
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/dbfs/PATH/test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    print([col.value for col in row])
```

[image]

Just overwrite the file with same name.

Comment: @akhetos No issue as yours after I test my code using openpyxl, please see my update.

Comment: sorry to bother you, I have edited the question since i can not reproduce you'r code. I found a solution but it's look like my environnement is not working well.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it by saving the file locally in Databricks, then I copy it to the desired mount.

```
import datetime
import shutil
# df = your dataframe
now_= datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp_ = datetime.datetime.timestamp(now_)
tmp_path = f'temp_{timestamp_}.xlsx' # I save it with the timestamp to avoid errors
writer = ExcelWriter(tmp_path)
real_path = f'{YOURPATH}_filename.xlsx'
df.to_excel(writer,'sheet_name')
writer.save()
shutil.copy(tmp_path, real_path) # Copy the temp file to mount
```