# Modifying the xlsx file using openpyxl in databricks directly without pandas/dataframe

Tags: python, databricks, openpyxl, azure-databricks

```
import openpyxl
input_workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('/dbfs/FileStore/Test/my_excel.xlsx')
sheet_1 = input_workbook1.active
sheet_1['A2'] = 'A2'
input_workbook1.save('/dbfs/FileStore/Test/Output.xlsx')  
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

I tried reading the excel file directly using openpyxl in databricks , I can able to read and modify directly without pandas/dataframes, but when I am trying to save i.e last line in above code facing the issue.[I tried exactly the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790643/data-brick-write-xlsx-in-dbsf-data-brick-file-system) but facing the above error , can anyone help me please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Write to Excel not working in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried doing the same procedure and it gave me the same error **OSError: [Errno 95]** Operation not supported. The reason for this is that there is a limitation that random writes do not work on the local file system and here is the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--local-file-api-limitations:%7E:text=Local%20file%20API%20limitations:%7E:text=Local%20file%20API%20limitations) (Local File API limitations) which refers to this issue.

So, try instead of trying to write to the local file system, write the file to `/databricks/driver/` path and then `copy/move` the file to required directory.

**Modify your code as following:**

```
import openpyxl
input_workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('/dbfs/FileStore/Test/my_excel.xlsx')
sheet_1 = input_workbook1.active
sheet_1['A2'] = 'A2'
input_workbook1.save('Output.xlsx')
#will be saved to '/databricks/driver/'.
#Use dbutils.fs.ls('/databricks/driver/') to view.
from shutil import move
move('/databricks/driver/Output.xlsx','/dbfs/FileStore/Test/')
```

[image: Ref1]

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('/dbfs/FileStore/Output.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active
for row in ws1.iter_rows():
    print([col.value for col in row])
```

[image: Ref2]

The above code will successfully move your file to the required path without any errors.

Comment: For me `/databricks/driver/` is not available, only available path are: `dbfs:/FileStore/` , `dbfs:/databricks-datasets/`  and `dbfs:/databricks-results/`. If I don't specify any folder when writing using `pd.to_excel('my_excel.xlsx')`, I got no errors but I cannot find the file.

Comment: First `import os`. Using `os.listdir("/databricks/driver/")` returns a list of its contents where you can find `my_excel.xlsx`

Comment: **It worked**, the `/databricks/driver/` pass belongs to the spark driver file system? Just for curiosity, why did not work with the dbutils?