# Writing pandas dataframe to excel in dbfs azure databricks: OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Tags: pandas, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to write a pandas dataframe to the local file system in azure databricks:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Business-price-indexes/Business-price-indexes-March-2019-quarter/Download-data/business-price-indexes-march-2019-quarter-csv.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'/dbfs/tmp/export.xlsx', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer)
```

Then I get the following error message:

> OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 3 data = pd.read_csv(url)
> 4 with pd.ExcelWriter(r'/dbfs/tmp/export.xlsx', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
> ----> 5     data.to_excel(writer)
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py
> in **exit**(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
> 892
> 893     def **exit**(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
> --> 894         self.close()
> 895
> 896     def close(self):
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py
> in close(self)
> 896     def close(self):
> 897         """synonym for save, to make it more file-like"""
> --> 898         content = self.save()
> 899         self.handles.close()
> 900         return content

I read in this post some limitations for mounted file systems: [Pandas: Write to Excel not working in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks)

But if I got it right, the solution is to write to the local workspace file system, which is exactly what is not working for me.

My user is workspace admin and I am using a standard cluster with 10.4 Runtime.

I also verified I can write csv file to the same location using pd.to_csv

What could be missing.

Comment: This question is not solving my problem but at least clarified why is not working.

Comment: With a comment on [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72918722/modifying-the-xlsx-file-using-openpyxl-in-databricks-directly-without-pandas-dat/72919601#72919601) I was able to solved it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Write to Excel not working in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Databricks has a drawback that does not allow random write operations into DBFS which is indicated in the SO thread you are referring to.
- So, a workaround for this would be to write the file to local file system (`file:/`) and then move to the required location inside DBFS. You can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Business-price-indexes/Business-price-indexes-March-2019-quarter/Download-data/business-price-indexes-march-2019-quarter-csv.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url)

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'export.xlsx', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    #file will be written to /databricks/driver/ i.e., local file system
    data.to_excel(writer)
```

- **dbutils.fs.ls("/databricks/driver/")** indicates that the path you want to use to list the files is **`dbfs:/databricks/driver/`** (absolute path) which does not exist.
- **/databricks/driver/** belongs to the **local file system** (*DBFS is a part of this*). The absolute path of `/databricks/driver/` is **`file:/databricks/driver/`**. You can list the contents of this path by using either of the following:

```
import os
print(os.listdir("/databricks/driver/")

#OR

dbutils.fs.ls("file:/databricks/driver/")
```

[image]

- So, use the file located in this path and move (*or copy*) it to your destination using `shutil` library as the following:

```
from shutil import move
move('/databricks/driver/export.xlsx','/dbfs/tmp/export.xlsx')
```